# WebSocket: можно ли использовать одно подключение для всего сайта?

Tags: html, websocket

Можно ли, установив *WebSocket* соединение на главной страничке сайта, продолжать пользоваться этим же соединением на всех остальных страничках? Или каждая страничка должна инициировать своё соединение?
Почему-то все примеры по использованию *WebSocket* ограничиваются лишь одним *html* файлом. Пожалуйста, проясните этот момент.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Соединение рвётся, когда вы уходите со страницы (даже если на другую страницу того же сайта). Так что каждая страница должна инициировать соединение заново

Comment: а что если не перезагружать страницу, а делать всё как spa?

Comment: @programmer403 Тогда соединение рватся не будет, логично. Собственно, это одна из основных причин делать SPA в моей практике )